# Order results based on SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I currently query a table for items with a certain `category`. I have extended this query to also looks within the item `description` column too. My question is, how do i order results so that the `category` matches are first and the description is last?

```
`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE `category` LIKE '%keyword%' || `description` LIKE '%keyword%'
```

In my above query simply adding a `ORDER BY category` will not suffice. The only way I can think of doing this is two separate queries with two separate result variables.

I'm using `php` and `mysqli`

Comment: I would go with two queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done like this

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE `category` LIKE '%keyword%' || `description` LIKE '%keyword%'
ORDER BY
    CASE
      WHEN `category` LIKE '%keyword%' THEN 1
      WHEN `description` LIKE '%keyword%' THEN 0
END
```

Comment: I never thought of a case statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done like this

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE `category` LIKE '%keyword%' || `description` LIKE '%keyword%'
ORDER BY
    CASE
      WHEN `category` LIKE '%keyword%' THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END CASE
      DESC
```

If you would like to broaden that SQL query and preserve these ordering, you can utilize:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE `category` LIKE '%keyword%' || `description` LIKE '%keyword%'
ORDER BY
    CASE
      WHEN `category` LIKE '%keyword%' THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END CASE
      DESC,
    CASE
      WHEN `description` LIKE '%keyword%' THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END CASE
      DESC
```

Results, what are both `description` results and `category` results, will be on begin - as it was not specified, I suppose, that *so* it is requested or accepted.